# Generating permutations of a given string that have a condition

Tags: c++, string, conditional-statements, permutation

How would I set up positional conditions when doing permutations of a given string, for example the string "ABC", given a condition such as B cannot be after A (B always has to be used before A), this will result in only:

```
BAC
BCA
CBA
```

Instead of:

```
ABC
ACB
BAC
BCA
CAB
CBA
```

How would this be possible without generating all the permutations first and then only testing the condition?  (I want to skip the route instead of testing the permutations afterwords is mainly the time it takes to go through longer strings.)

Currently I'm using back-tracing to get rid of the combinations where B is directly after A and skipping the route, however I'm having problems testing if its anywhere after A in the string ACB will still show up.

Answer (score 0):

You might construct your prefix and suffix independently, something like:

```
void foo(std::string prefix, std::string suffix)
{
    do
    {
        do
        {
            std::cout << prefix << "B" << suffix << std::endl;   
        } while (std::next_permutation(suffix.begin(), suffix.end()));
    } while (std::next_permutation(prefix.begin(), prefix.end()));
}

std::pair<std::string, std::string> split(const std::string& letters, unsigned int flag)
{
    std::string prefix{"A"};
    std::string suffix;

    for (auto c : letters) {
        if (flag & 1) {
            prefix.push_back(c);
        } else {
            suffix.push_back(c);
        }
        flag >>= 1;
    }
    return {std::move(prefix), std::move(suffix)};
}

void foo(std::string letters)
{
    //assert(letters.size() < 31); // else would require some dynamic bitset
    auto max = 1 << letters.size();
    std::sort(letters.begin(), letters.end());

    for (int i = 0; i != max; ++i) {
        auto [prefix, suffix] = split(letters, i);

        foo(prefix, suffix);
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f5817c55feb5d5b)